# Change email address in stackexchange jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I'm not able to find where to change the email address shown in stackoverflow jobs that would show up in the red marked area of the screenshot. Can someone please help?
[image: email stackoverflow jobs]

Comment: Is it not just the email used in https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current

Comment: @ Nick A you are absolutely right.

Comment: Although it might be nice to be able to set your contact email on jobs to a different email from your SE one

Comment: I found one can set different email addresses for communities and stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current